# What is the best way to read a PDF in Android?

Tags: android

I want to read a PDF in my application so which is the best way for that?

- PDF to image convert and show.
- direct PDF reads form server using PDF reader.

Answer (score 1):

There are set of libraries and sdk you can use to read pdf in android.

http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: I used `qoppa`, its simple to use, but its expensive for indie developers

Comment: thanks ramjibhai..i have already download this reader but i have no idea how can use in my android project...